# How to start service project on android ?

Tags: android

i need to write simple android application that run on the background and read any sms message that comes - and do some change on the massage that come from phone number XXXX .

This application dont need any GUI - so i dont need to use any Activity.

I started a new project on Eclipse and there is no option to define that the project will be service - just define it as activity.

How can i start a project to be a service ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<service android:name=".YourService" />

<receiver android:name="com.your.package.AutoStart">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Create class AutoStart.java:

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);       
    }

}
```

The OS will call your AutoStart.onReceive() method when the device is booted. Note that this may be before the SD card is mounted. When you install the apk, the system will look at your manifest and your app will be registered with the system for you to start on boot.

Answer (score 1):

There's info in the developer guide on how to do this. You have to specify that the app is a service in its manifest. From the guide:

> To declare your service, add a  element as a child of the
>    element. For example:
>
> ```
> <manifest ... >
>   ...
>   <application ... >
>       <service android:name=".ExampleService" />
>       ...
>   </application>
> </manifest>
> ```

Here's the link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Comment: SO start the project as same way as Activity ?